# Comand on text file needs to be run in putty

Tags: putty

I have logged into a server using putty, now i want to run some commands saved in my laptop in a txt file. Please help me how can i get is done. I need all the commands to be run in that particular  server as is contains 20-25 line of command and i do not want to fire all these commands one one by one. if it is possible to run all automatically it will be a great help for me and time saving also.

Comment: Typically the method would be to "create a script" which may be as simple as transferring your existing text file to the target system and executing it.  It will help if you clarify your question, eg to say what operating system the target system is running

Comment: You do realize you can simply copy and paste all the commands in your text file directly into PuTTY right, and that will run the command from the first line all the way to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use plink with the `-m` parameter instead of putty.

```
-m file   read remote command(s) from file
```

Alternatively, if you only need to do this one time you can just open your file with a text editor, copy the whole content to the clipboard and paste it into putty by clicking with the right mouse button into the putty window.